# navbar-header and navbar-nav are not lining up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am having trouble getting my navbar-header and navbar-nav items to line up properly.  The navbar-header is centered vertically in the navbar, while the navbar-nav looks like it is align="top".

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

and here is the code for the menu:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                @Html.ActionLink("Thomas A Farmer, Author", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="~/Home/Index">Home</a> |
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a> |
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="~/Home/About">About the Author</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Home/BKB">Black Knight Books</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/Home/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="~/MailingListEntries/Create">Mailing List</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Books and Stories <span class="caret"></span></a> |
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Novels", "Index", "BooksAndStories", new { novel = true }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Short Stories", "Index", "BooksAndStories", new { novel = false }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("WIP", "WIP", "BooksAndStories", null, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="~/Reviews/Index">Reviews</a> |
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="~/OtherProjects/Index">Other Projects</a> |
                </li>
                @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Admin Tools<span class="caret"></span></a>
                        |
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="~/MailingListEntries/Index"> Edit Mailing List</a></li>
                            <li><a href="~/Blog/Create">Add Blog Entry</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
            @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - TAFarmerAuthor</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

Anyone have any ideas?  I'm still learning MVC and Razor, and I haven't been able to find any answers on google that speak directly to this problem.

Comment: This doesnt answer your question, but just a recommendation. You should use asp-tag helpers, it will help you navigate better.

Comment: @Carthax, `navbar-nav` and `navbar-header` are `bootstrap` style rules.  You can override these style rules if you want.  I believe there is an extra padding or margin from your `navbar-item`, have a look at that in developer's tool of your browser's choice.

Answer (score 0):

--edit: what version of bootstrap are you using?  What you are showing us is like 3.x

--edit2: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/components/#navbar is the version you using... I suggest moving to 4.3.1...

if this is the newest version of bootstrap you missed a tag within the class attributes

//original snippet

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="~/home/index">Home</a> |
...
```

//Modified

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
     <a href="~/home/index" class="nav-link">Home</a> |
   ...
```

as @Derrick Rose suggested if you are using .net core or even .netframework with MVC then you are definitely doing it the hard way with the your `<a>` tags.
   `<a asp-controller="home" asp-action="Index" class="nav-link">Home</a>|` looks way better...

```
   <li>@Html.ActionLink("Novels", "Index", "BooksAndStories", new { novel = true }, htmlAttributes: null)</li>
```

turns into

```
  <li><a asp-action="Index" class="nav-link" asp-controller="BooksAndStories" asp-route-novel="true">Novels</a></li>
```